# Laravel 4 restful delete a record with a resource controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am new to Laravel framework but I really like it.
My biggest problem is I have been searching on how I can delete a single record using resource controller.

Controller method:

```
public function destroy($id) {
    $department = Department::find($id);
    $department->delete();
}
```

Delete link I have tried:

```
<a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-method="delete" href="{{ URL::to('department/' . $department->id) }}"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('[data-method]').append(function(){
        return "\n" +
        "form action='" + $(this).attr('href') + "' method='post' style='display: none;'>\n" + 
        "<input type='hidden' name='_method' value='"+$(this).attr('data-method')+"'>\n" +
        "</form>\n"
    })
    .removeAttr('href')
    .attr('style', 'cursor: pointer;')
    .attr('onclick', '$(this).find("form").submit();');
});
```

Now when I click on the delete link, it doesn't work.
Any idea on what am I doing wrong, I have been searching for so long.

Comment: Use ``<a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-method="delete" href="{{ URL::to('department/' . $department->id) }}"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>`` without the javascript. The destroy should be called from ``DELETE`` request.

Comment: Now that you got your answer, I would like to point out issues with your code if you don't mind. Why do you write the form in `domReady` and not already in your backend? Same goes for the `style` and `onclick` attributes. Furthermore, you can replace your `onclick` with `jQuery.click()` for obvious reasons. But the main question is: Why don't you - as suggested in multiple answers - use `jQuery.ajax()`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to trigger your click instead of that form creation/submission:

```
$(document).on("click", "[data-method]", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.post($(this).attr('href'), {/* the id goes here */});
});
```

Apply the cursor style via CSS. I must admit that I'm not sure if laravel expects a HTTP DELETE instead of a post. And I think you missed to submit the id of the department you want to delete.

[edit]
As laravel expects a HTTP DELETE you can't use the $.post() shorthand, but [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead:

```
$(document).on("click", "[data-method]", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        type: "DELETE",
        data: {/* the id goes here */},
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
             console.log("success");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a minor mistake. I just forgot to put < at the beginning of the form declaration ie "form blah blah" instead of "<form blah blah"

Answer (score 1):

The `destroy()` will be called in `DELETE` request and not in `POST` request.

So try ,

```
<a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" onclick="deleteDepartment($department->id)" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
```

And in javascript,

```
function deleteDepartment(id) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'department/'+id,
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(result) {
        // Do something with the result
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a minor mistake. I just forgot to put < at the beginning of the form declaration ie "form blah blah" instead of "<form blah blah"

Comment: Using _method you can spoof HTTP methods in laravel 
http://laravel.com/docs/html#opening-a-form

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers guys, it works just as it is I just forgot the opening < when creating a form ie I was mistakenly wrote:

```
"form action='" + $(this).attr('href') + "' method='post' style='display: none;'>\n" +
```

Instead of:

```
"<form action='" + $(this).attr('href') + "' method='post' style='display: none;'>\n" +
```